# How to implement multiple jibri servers with autoscale

Tags: jitsi-meet

I have implemented following 2 approaches.

1. I have done jitsi setup in which my jitsi, jvb and jibri running on seperate server.
2. I have done jitsi setup using docker in which I am using different containers to run jibri servers.
   both set up are working fine but I am unable to autoscale jibri in any of them. I have searched alot over this topics, didn't find any reliable solution for this.
   Please help if anyone has idea about how to autoscale jibri servers for multiple video recordings.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jibri with pulseaudio and use hpa for scailing.
please see this [rep](https://github.com/prayagsingh/docker-jibri-pulseaudio)o

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30014856)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jibri On Demand service. It is a SaaS so you dont need to worry autoscaling.
Configure AWS S3 IAM accesskey and secretkey, the finalize script will upload recordings to your bucket.
The price is ok if i only want to handle peaks.
My configuration is 1 dedicated server host by my own, others handled by JibriOnDemand.